# Cast Function with multiple rows and a time column

Tags: casting, panel, subset, dataformat

I have a big Eurostat dataset loaded like this:

```
install.packages("SmarterPoland")
library(SmarterPoland)
GDP_raw <- getEurostatRCV(kod = "namq_gdp_c")
```

It has this structure:

```
    s_adj   unit        indic_na    geo     time        value
1   NSA     EUR_HAB     B11         AT      2014Q1      NA
2   NSA     EUR_HAB     B11         BE      2014Q1      200.0
3   NSA     EUR_HAB     B11         BG      2014Q1      -100.0
```

I want to use "time" as the first column and the other variables as rows. Doing it the other way around is easy with:

```
GDP_sorted <- cast(GDP_raw, geo + unit + s_adj + indic_na ~ time)
```

which returns:

```
    geo unit      s_adj   indic_na  1955Q1  1955Q2  1955Q3  1955Q4
1   AT  EUR_HAB   NSA     B11       NA      NA      NA      NA
2   AT  EUR_HAB   NSA     B111      NA      NA      NA      NA
3   AT  EUR_HAB   NSA     B112      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

The problem is, that here the columns are variables so every quarter is its own variable which doesn't make sense from a Time Series perspective. I need some sort of transpose (simple t() doesn't return the same data type). However, if I try cast the other way around, it adds the different categories together into one variable and creates:

```
        time     AT_EUR_HAB_NSA_B11   AT_EUR_HAB_NSA_B111     AT_EUR_HAB_NSA_B112
1       1955Q1   NA                   NA                      NA
2       1955Q2   NA                   NA                      NA
3       1955Q3   NA                   NA                      NA
```

Which means I have 12405 variables. That makes subset infeasible. I'd like something along the lines of:

```
        time
s_adj            NSA                 NSA                     NSA
geo              AT                  AT                      AT
unit             EUR_HAB             EUR_HAB                 EUR_HAB
indic_na         B11                 B12                     B13
1       1955Q1   NA                   NA                      NA
2       1955Q2   NA                   NA                      NA
3       1955Q3   NA                   NA                      NA
```

and so forth (this is a fictional example). So then I could use:

```
Demand <- subset(GDP_sorted, (indic_na == "P3_P5") & (s_adj == "SWDA") & (unit == "MIO_EUR"))
```

Without having to specify all combinations of variables from 12405 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Until someone provides a better answer, here is a workaround I'm using now:

start from the raw downloaded table:

```
GDP_raw <- read.table("/media/38A05C6AA05C311C/1_Documents/Dropbox/Masterarbeit/2_R/Data/GDP_raw.RData")
```

then subset your variable of interest:

```
Demand <- subset(GDP_raw, (indic_na == "P3_P5") & (s_adj == "SWDA") & (unit == "MIO_EUR"))
```

and then the only dimensions which remain are time and geo which you can cast simply as:

```
Demand_cast <- cast(Demand, time ~ geo)
```

Which gives you one file with the matrix of your variable of the form:

```
time    AT  BE  BG
1955Q1  NA  NA  NA
1955Q2  NA  NA  NA
1955Q3  NA  NA  NA
```